# Deploying safe-contracts to Astar Network

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to deploy the **Safe Protocol** (Smart Contracts + Safe API architecture) to **Astar** Network. I am facing the issue of deploying Smart Contracts to Astar. The error I am facing now is -  **`Error: nonce has already been used`** which occurs at `deploy_accessors.ts` file in the `safe-contracts` repo.
Steps I followed:-

1. Added mnemonic and other relevant data to the `.env`.
2. Ran the `yarn compile 592` in the `safe-singleton-factory` repo. 592 being the chain ID for the Astar network.
3. Linked the `safe-contracts` repo to the local `safe-singleton-factory` repo to get the apt. deployment data for the respective chain ID.
4. In the `safe-contracts` repo, ran the `yarn deploy astar` which has all the relevant info regarding the `astar` network in `hardhat.config` file.

It would be great if someone from the Gnosis team can help me out here as I am trying to bring new chain support to the Gnosis ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing nonce in deploy_accesors or use a new wallet for it